# How to send an argument with an addEventListener to a function?

Tags: javascript, arguments, addeventlistener

I'm quite new to coding and I ran into this tiny problem. I want to send an argument with the addEventListener. When I tried to send an argument with the EventListener it ran the function immediately. I know it's because I have the () after the function name. What I tried to do is basically this:

```
var card1 = document.getElementById('#id1');
card1.addEventListener('click',choose(1));

function(num){
 var picture = 'pictures/picture1.png';
 document.getElementById(num).src = pic.replace('90x90','225x225');
```

This is all javascript code, and its purpose is to change a picture. The var picture is in reality chosen based on some arrays in my code, but it's just an image.

Comment: The second argument in `addEventListener` needs to be a function, does `choose()` return an event function?

Comment: your function choose doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

Invoke/Call the function inside of an anonymous function:

```
card1.addEventListener('click', function(){ choose(1); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options:

1) Use bind to create a new function with the parameter already filled in:

```js
var card1 = document.getElementById('#id1');
var choose = function( num ) {
  console.log( num );
};
card1.addEventListener('click', choose.bind(null,1));
```

```html
<button id="#id1">Card 1</button>
```

2) Return a function from inside `choose()`. This is almost the same as using `.bind()`:

```js
var card1 = document.getElementById('#id1');
var choose = function( num ) {
  return function( event ) {
    console.log( num );
  };
};
card1.addEventListener('click', choose(1));
```

```html
<button id="#id1">Card 1</button>
```

3) Have the card element tell you the number:

```js
var card1 = document.getElementById('#id1');
var choose = function( event ) {
  var num = event.target.getAttribute( 'data-number' );
  console.log( num );
};
card1.addEventListener('click', choose );
```

```html
<button id="#id1" data-number="1">Card 1</button>
```

4) The other answer below also creates another function, but by writing it directly instead of by returning it or by using `.bind()`.

Which one to use depends entirely on what is appropriate in your project, your own preferences, the signature of other things that might use `choose()`, etc.

Comment: seems like you missed the most common way

Comment: @epascarello The one written by Mamun below? Didn't think I had to repeat it. Or do you mean something we both missed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a dynamic listener to each card, you can have your `click` event return a function call with the target card and index.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card, index) => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    chooseCard(e.target, index + 1);
  });
});

function chooseCard(card, num) {
  card.classList.toggle('card-' + num);
}
```

```css
.cards {
  background: green;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/AAA/F00?text=CARD') center no-repeat;
}

.card-1 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=1') }
.card-2 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=2') }
.card-3 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=3') }
.card-4 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=4') }
.card-5 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=5') }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

### Data Attribute

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card, index) => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    chooseCard(e.target);
  });
});

function chooseCard(card) {
  card.classList.toggle('card-' + card.getAttribute('data-index'));
}
```

```css
.cards {
  background: green;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/AAA/F00?text=CARD') center no-repeat;
}

.card-1 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=1') }
.card-2 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=2') }
.card-3 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=3') }
.card-4 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=4') }
.card-5 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=5') }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" data-index="1"></div>
  <div class="card" data-index="2"></div>
  <div class="card" data-index="3"></div>
  <div class="card" data-index="4"></div>
  <div class="card" data-index="5"></div>
</div>
```

### Child Index

```js
const getChildIndex = (el) => [].indexOf.call(el.parentNode.children, el);

document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card, index) => {
  card.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    chooseCard(e.target);
  });
});

function chooseCard(card) {
  card.classList.toggle('card-' + (getChildIndex(card) + 1));
}
```

```css
.cards {
  background: green;
  width: 330px;
  height: 100px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/AAA/F00?text=CARD') center no-repeat;
}

.card-1 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=1') }
.card-2 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=2') }
.card-3 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=3') }
.card-4 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=4') }
.card-5 { background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50x80/FFF/00F?text=5') }
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```